# Gadget mass storage passthrough

Tags: kernel, usb

I'm using Yocto in kernel 4.14 (computer 1). I have two USB port :

Host : with a USB key (mass storage device) plugged

OTG  : connected to another computer (computer 2)

```
             ################    ###############
|USB_KEY|----## COMPUTER 1 ##----## COMPUTER 2##---|screen, keyboard, ...
             ################    ###############
           ^                   ^
      USB link 1            USB link 2
```

I am trying to access the USB key connected on the computer 1 from the computer 2.

I use g_ether gadget with the USB link 2 and I should use another gadget module like a mass storage gadget.

Can the computer 1 passthrough to a mass storage gadget?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the solution was :

```
g_multi
```

**Edit :**

g_multi is the gadget usb called "Multifunction Composite Gadget" in Kernel.
This module have two options :

```
< > Multifunction Composite Gadget
[ ]    RNDIS + CDC Serial + Storage configuration
[ ]    CDC Ethernet + CDC Serial + Storage configuration
```

In my case I use the first option. But I have no reson to use the CDC Serial.

To enable it :

```
modprobe g_multi file=/dev/sda # sda is your USB mass storage device
```

This command will creates both usb0 network interface and mass storage device on host device. It also creates CDC Serial.

Now I use the USB gadget set up though configfs.
See the documentaion :
[Gadget configfs documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget_configfs.txt)

With this "new" USB gadget system you will choose which all gadgets you want.

Comment: Can you explain exactly how you used `g_multi`?